# Basis change formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about basis change formula
So i have 2 basis B1 and B2, [B1],[B2] matrix with vectors from these basis
If X is the matrix for crosssing from B1 to B2, what is the equation that is verified by X?

X = [B1] ^ (-1) * [B2] or X = [B2] ^ (-1) * [B1]?
How is correct?
Sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "the matrix for crossing from $B_1$ to $B_2$"?

If $B_1$ and $B_2$ are both bases for a vector space, then there exists an invertible matrix $C_{B_1B_2}$ called the *transition* matrix which takes a vector from $B_2$ to $B_2$.

For example, suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $B_1$, $B_2$ are bases of $V$. For $v \in V$ in terms of the basis $B_2$, then $C_{B_1B_2}v$ is that same vector but in terms of the basis $B_1$.

Comment: Yes ! Transition matrix (instead of crossing). Which is formula?